# How to solve $\frac{y''}{y} = -\frac{2}{9x^2}$ without guessing?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the second-order differential equation 
$$ \frac{y''}{y} = -\frac{2}{9x^2} $$

By trial and error, I found that $y=x^{1/3}$ and $y=x^{2/3}$ satisfy the equation. So, all solutions are of the form $y = ax^{1/3} + bx^{2/3}$ as long as $y\not= 0$.

How could I go about solving a differential equation like this analytically?

Comment: Have you tried separation of variables and integrating twice?

Comment: @Ziryerx Yes, I did, I got $(\ln(y)-1)y = \frac{2}{9}\ln(x)$ and didn't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: Perhaps one of $y$ is $y'$.

Comment: you can use frobenius method

Comment: @MyGlasses  In the original problem, no, it's definitely $y''$. I didn't come across this problem for a math class--I encountered it while reading physics

Comment: furthermore note that $(x^a)''$ yields $a (a-1)x^{(a-2)}$ which makes a solution of this type quiet plausible (since the rhs is also a simple power of x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation).
Putting it in that form:
$$9x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2y=0$$

You can use the ansatz $y=x^{\lambda}$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\lambda x^{\lambda-1}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\lambda(\lambda-1)x^{\lambda-2}$$
To obtain the polynomial:
$$9\lambda^2-9\lambda+2=0$$

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this as soon as I can. Out of curiosity, are there any slightly more general methods for non Cauchy-Euler equations? I.e. what if the right hand side was $-\frac{9}{2x^3}$

Comment: elegant! ($+1$)...

Comment: @aras In that case, I do not know. I checked [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2Fy%3D-9%2F(2x%5E3)) and saw that it would be in terms of [Bessel Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the first and second kind.

Comment: @projectilemotion Hm, interesting. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Isn't an ansatz simply a guess?

Comment: @Dr.MV Well, strictly speaking it is. However, I think the OP means 'guessing' in the context of trial-and-error.

Comment: @projectilemotion (+1) for the post

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Your statement is false.  There are a host of methodologies that are not "sort of guesswork."  Aside from that, I up voted the answer.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Do you need to guess anything about the solution to the ODE $$y'(t)+\mu(t)y(t)=f(t)$$with $y(0)=y_0$?  And the method of Frobenius isn't really guess work,, is it? And use of Green (of Green's if you prefer) function is not guess work.  And Fourier series expansions is not guess work.  What are you talking about?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck The other methodologies that I referenced apply to higher-order differential equations.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I listed (1) the method of Frobenius, (2) Green (Green's) Functions, and (3) Fourier series expansions. Why are you asking about Laplace Transforms?