# Solving differential equation: $y''-\frac{\epsilon ^2 y}{x^2} + \frac{y'}{x}=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I've derived a differential equation, as below.

$$y''(x)-\frac{\epsilon ^2 y(x)}{x^2} + \frac{y'(x)}{x}=0$$

It is a second order linear differential equation, WolframAlpha seem to suggest that the solution is (for the equation without $\epsilon$):

$$y(x) = \frac{(c_1 (x^2 + 1))}{x} + \frac{(i c_2 (x^2 - 1))}{(2 x)}$$

I have two questions:

1. What is the step-by-step towards the solution?
2. Why is there imaginary part in the solution?

Would be appreciated for any help!

Comment: Cauchy-Euler are in da hood
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182186/how-to-solve-fracyy-frac29x2-without-guessing

Comment: @tired, I am looking at WolframAlpha, it seems to suggest the Cauchy-Euler, Emden‐Fowler, Sturm‐Liouville...

Comment: HINT: $$x^{\epsilon},x^{-\epsilon}$$ are solutions

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, looking, thanks :)

Comment: Actually, this is a **linear** differential equation.

Comment: @projectilemotion, changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation).
Putting it in that form:
$$x^2\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}-\epsilon^2 y=0$$

You can use the ansatz $y=x^{\lambda}$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\lambda x^{\lambda-1}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\lambda(\lambda-1)x^{\lambda-2}$$
To obtain the polynomial:
$$-\epsilon^2+\lambda^2=0$$
Solving for $\lambda$ and using the fact that $y(x)=c_1 y_1(x)+c_2 y_2(x)$, we obtain the general solution.

---

**To answer your second question:**

Do not be alarmed that the solution given by the above looks different when letting $\epsilon=1$. Wolfram|Alpha in this case did not give the simplest solution. Let's continue from the answer given:
$$y(x)=\frac{c_1(x^2+1)}{x}+\frac{ic_2(x^2-1)}{x}=c_1\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+i\cdot c_2\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
Grouping terms:
$$y(x)=x\cdot (c_1+i\cdot c_2)+\frac{1}{x}\cdot (c_1-i\cdot c_2)$$
Since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are **arbitrary constants**, we may let $c_1+ic_2=k_1$ and $c_1-ic_2=k_2$. This gives a simple solution, which is consistent with the solution we obtain for general $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that we want the solution for $0<x$, so multiply both sides by $x^2$.  Yield the following:

$$ x^2y'' +xy' - \epsilon^2y = 0$$

Guess that the solution looks like $y = x^r$.  Then,

$$x^2r(r-1)x^{r-2} + xrx^{r-1} + \epsilon x^r = 0$$

Factor out the $x^r$ which is not zero by assumption. You are left with something quadratic in $r$

Comment: thank you, your solution is helpful.